# Twig output not styled correctly

Tags: 9

In one of my twig templates, I have:

`<pre>{{ dump() }}</pre>`

Twig output looks like:

```
Sfdump = window.Sfdump || (function (doc) {
```

[image]

Controller (partial code):

```
$renderable = [
  '#theme' => 'child-profile',
  '#profile' => $records,
];
$output = Drupal::service('renderer')->renderPlain($renderable);
return [
  '#type' => 'markup',
  '#markup' => $output,
];
```

How can I get this to be styled correctly? It looks like it's outputting the javascript as text instead of executing it.

Comment: Are any Drupal debugging modules running on that site?

Comment: Also, it would be good to know what the actual markup is on that page just before and in the beginning of, the dump output.